# Dynamic Web Twain - PHP - Adding Additional HTML Fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, twain, dynamic-web-twain

I've got a Laravel project but I think I have an idea of how to incorporate the Dynamic Web Twain (https://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/WebTWAIN_Overview.aspx) into it.

The only problem is I'm not quite sure how I would go about adding additional fields to the scanner UI (like what you see here: https://demo.dynamsoft.com/dwt/online_demo_scan.aspx).

At the moment my Laravel site has a working upload portion to a model where I can submit attachments, however, with the attachment form are fields that include "visibility", "type", "upload location" etc. etc. But I can't seem to figure out how I would add fields like what I already use.

From what I've tested, this is an incredibly useful tool and would work well if I could integrate it into all aspects of my site.

The closest thing I can find is here: https://developer.dynamsoft.com/dwt/api-reference/uploading-downloading/sethttpformfield

Which references what is done in this demo: https://demo.dynamsoft.com/Samples/dwt/Scan-Documents-and-Upload-Them/DWT_Scan_Upload_Demo.html

As you can see, you can add a field name and field value, using the "+" button, but I want to add some fields in the form that are available immediately. The other issue that I might need to work around is if I use this demo and add a value and name, this is how everything is posted and I'm not sure how to translate to something my project can understand.

```
-----------------------------23491353817351
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="This is a field"

Wow
-----------------------------23491353817351
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="RemoteFile"; filename="507-0.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

ÿØÿà
```

This aspect is a necessary part of my project, so unfortunately there's no real way around this besides moving forward.

This is the current script in the online demo:

```
Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.RegisterEvent('OnWebTwainReady', Dynamsoft_OnReady); // Register OnWebTwainReady event. This event fires as soon as Dynamic Web TWAIN is initialized and ready to be used

var DWObject, blankField = "", extrFieldsCount = 0, upload_returnSth = true;
var CurrentPathName = unescape(location.pathname);
var CurrentPath = CurrentPathName.substring(0, CurrentPathName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
var strHTTPServer = location.hostname;
var strActionPage;

var scriptLanguages = [
    { desc: "PHP", val: "php" },
    { desc: "PHP-MySQL", val: "phpMySQL" },
    { desc: "CSharp", val: "csharp" },
    { desc: "CSharp-MSSQL", val: "csMSSQL" },
    { desc: "VB.NET", val: "vbnet" },
    { desc: "VBNET-MSSQL", val: "vbnetMSSQL" },
    { desc: "JSP", val: "jsp" },
    { desc: "JSP-Oracle", val: "jspOracle" },
    { desc: "ASP", val: "asp" },
    { desc: "ASP-MSSQL", val: "aspMSSQL" },
    { desc: "ColdFusion", val: "cfm" },
    { desc: "CS-Azure", val: "csAzure" }
];

function languageSelected() {
    if (document.getElementById("ddlLanguages").selectedIndex > 7)
        upload_returnSth = false;
    else
        upload_returnSth = true;
    if ([0, 2, 4, 6].indexOf(document.getElementById("ddlLanguages").selectedIndex) == -1) {
        document.getElementById("extra-fields-div-id").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('div-extra-fields').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("extra-fields-div-id").style.display = '';
        if (document.getElementById('div-extra-fields').children.length > 1 ||
        document.getElementById('div-extra-fields').children[0].children[0].value != '') {
            document.getElementById('div-extra-fields').style.display = '';
        }
    }
}


function addAField() {
    extrFieldsCount++;
    if (extrFieldsCount == 3) {
        document.getElementById('div-extra-fields').style.overflowY = 'scroll';
    }
    if (document.getElementById('div-extra-fields').style.display == "none")
        document.getElementById('div-extra-fields').style.display = '';
    else {
        document.getElementById('div-extra-fields').appendChild(blankField);
        blankField = document.getElementsByClassName('div-fields-item')[extrFieldsCount - 1].cloneNode(true);
    }
}

function downloadPDFR() {
    DCP_DWT_OnClickCloseInstall();
    DWObject.Addon.PDF.Download(
        CurrentPath + '/Resources/addon/Pdf.zip',
        function () {/*console.log('PDF dll is installed');*/
        },
        function (errorCode, errorString) {
            console.log(errorString);
        }
    );
}

function Dynamsoft_OnReady() {
    blankField = document.getElementsByClassName('div-fields-item')[0].cloneNode(true);
    DWObject = Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.GetWebTwain('dwtcontrolContainer'); // Get the Dynamic Web TWAIN object that is embeded in the div with id 'dwtcontrolContainer'
    if (DWObject) {
        DWObject.Width = 505;
        DWObject.Height = 600;
        for (var i = 0; i < scriptLanguages.length; i++)
            document.getElementById("ddlLanguages").options.add(new Option(scriptLanguages[i].desc, i));
        document.getElementById("ddlLanguages").options.selectedIndex = 2;
        /*
        * Make sure the PDF Rasterizer and OCR add-on are already installedsample
        */
        if (!Dynamsoft.Lib.env.bMac) {
            var localPDFRVersion = '';
            if(Dynamsoft.Lib.product.bChromeEdition){
                localPDFRVersion = DWObject._innerFun('GetAddOnVersion', '["pdf"]');
            }
            else {
                localPDFRVersion = DWObject.getSWebTwain().GetAddonVersion("pdf");
            }
            if (localPDFRVersion != Dynamsoft.PdfVersion) {
                var ObjString = [];
                ObjString.push('<div class="p15" id="pdfr-install-dlg">');
                ObjString.push('The <strong>PDF Rasterizer</strong> is not installed on this PC<br />Please click the button below to get it installed');
                ObjString.push('<p class="tc mt15 mb15"><input type="button" value="Install PDF Rasterizer" onclick="downloadPDFR();" class="btn lgBtn bgBlue" /><hr></p>');
                ObjString.push('<i><strong>The installation is a one-time process</strong> <br />It might take some time depending on your network.</i>');
                ObjString.push('</div>');
                Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.ShowDialog(400, 310, ObjString.join(''));
            }
            else {
                /**/
            }
        }
    }
}

function AcquireImage() {
    if (DWObject) {
        var bSelected = DWObject.SelectSource();
        if (bSelected) {
            var OnAcquireImageSuccess, OnAcquireImageFailure;
            OnAcquireImageSuccess = OnAcquireImageFailure = function () {
                DWObject.CloseSource();
            };

            DWObject.OpenSource();
            DWObject.IfDisableSourceAfterAcquire = true;  //Scanner source will be disabled/closed automatically after the scan.
            DWObject.AcquireImage(OnAcquireImageSuccess, OnAcquireImageFailure);
        }
    }
}

function LoadImages() {
    if (DWObject) {       
        DWObject.Addon.PDF.SetResolution(300);
        DWObject.Addon.PDF.SetConvertMode(EnumDWT_ConverMode.CM_RENDERALL);
        DWObject.LoadImageEx('', 5,
            function () {
            },
            function (errorCode, errorString) {
            alert('Load Image:' + errorString);
            }
        );
    }       
}
function OnHttpUploadSuccess() {
    console.log('successful');
}

function OnHttpServerReturnedSomething(errorCode, errorString, sHttpResponse) {
    //console.log(errorString);
    var textFromServer = sHttpResponse;
    _printUploadedFiles(textFromServer);
}

function _printUploadedFiles(info) {
    //console.log(info);
    if (info.indexOf('DWTUploadFileName') != -1) {
        var url, _strPort;
        DWObject.IfSSL = Dynamsoft.Lib.detect.ssl;
        _strPort = location.port == "" ? 80 : location.port
        url = 'http://' + location.hostname + ':' + location.port
        if (Dynamsoft.Lib.detect.ssl == true) {
            _strPort = location.port == "" ? 443 : location.port;
            url = 'https://' + location.hostname + ':' + location.port
        }
        var savedIntoToDB = false, imgIndexInDB = "-1";
        if (info.indexOf("DWTUploadFileIndex:") != -1) {
            savedIntoToDB = true;
            imgIndexInDB = info.substring(info.indexOf('DWTUploadFileIndex') + 19, info.indexOf('DWTUploadFileName'));
            //console.log(imgIndexInDB);
        }
        var fileName = info.substring(info.indexOf('DWTUploadFileName') + 18, info.indexOf('UploadedFileSize'));
        var fileSize = info.substr(info.indexOf('UploadedFileSize') + 17);
        if (savedIntoToDB) {
            if (info.indexOf('CSHARP') != -1) {
                url += CurrentPath + 'action/csharp-db.aspx?imgID=' + imgIndexInDB;
            }
            else if (info.indexOf('VBNET') != -1) {
                url += CurrentPath + 'action/vbnet-db.aspx?imgID=' + imgIndexInDB;
            }
            else if (info.indexOf('PHP') != -1) {
                url += CurrentPath + 'action/php-mysql.php?imgID=' + imgIndexInDB;
            }           
            else if (info.indexOf('JSP') != -1) {
                url += CurrentPath + 'action/jsp-oracle.jsp?imgID=' + imgIndexInDB;
            }
        }
        else {
            url += CurrentPath + 'action/UploadedImages/' + encodeURI(fileName);
        }
        var newTR = document.createElement('tr');
        _str = "<td class='tc'><a class='bluelink'" + ' href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + fileName + "</a></td>"
            + "<td class='tc'>" + fileSize + '</td>';
        if (info.indexOf("FieldsTrue:") != -1)
            _str += "<td class='tc'><a class='bluelink'" + '" href="' + url.substring(0, url.length - 4) + '_1.txt' + '" target="_blank">Fields</td>';
        else {
            _str += "<td class='tc'>No Fields</td>";
        }
        newTR.innerHTML = _str;
        document.getElementById('div-uploadedFile').appendChild(newTR);
    }
}

function upload_preparation(_name) {
    DWObject.IfShowCancelDialogWhenImageTransfer = !document.getElementById('quietScan').checked;
    strActionPage = CurrentPath + 'action/';
    switch (document.getElementById("ddlLanguages").options.selectedIndex) {
        case 0: strActionPage += "php.php"; break;
        case 2: strActionPage += "csharp.aspx"; break;
        case 6: strActionPage += "jsp.jsp"; break;
        case 4: strActionPage += "vbnet.aspx"; break;
        case 8: strActionPage += "asp.asp"; break;
        case 10: strActionPage += "cfm.cfm"; break;
        case 1: strActionPage += "php-mysql.php?imgID=new"; break;
        case 7: strActionPage += "jsp-oracle.jsp?imgID=new"; break;
        case 3: strActionPage += "csharp-db.aspx?imgID=new"; break;
        case 5: strActionPage += "vbnet-db.aspx?imgID=new"; break;
        case 9: strActionPage += "asp-db.asp"; break;
        case 11: preparetoUploadtoAzure(_name); break;
        default: break;
    }
    DWObject.IfSSL = Dynamsoft.Lib.detect.ssl;
    var _strPort = location.port == "" ? 80 : location.port;
    if (Dynamsoft.Lib.detect.ssl == true)
        _strPort = location.port == "" ? 443 : location.port;
    DWObject.HTTPPort = _strPort;
    if ([0, 2, 4, 6].indexOf(document.getElementById("ddlLanguages").selectedIndex) != -1) {
        /* Add Fields to the Post */
        var fields = document.getElementsByClassName('div-fields-item');

        DWObject.ClearAllHTTPFormField();
        for (var n = 0; n < fields.length; n++) {
            var o = fields[n];
            if (o.children[0].value != '')
                DWObject.SetHTTPFormField(o.children[0].value, o.children[1].value);
        }
    }
}
function UploadImage_inner() {
    if (DWObject.HowManyImagesInBuffer == 0)
        return;

    var Digital = new Date();
    var uploadfilename = Digital.getMilliseconds(); // Uses milliseconds according to local time as the file name
    upload_preparation(uploadfilename);

    // Upload the image(s) to the server asynchronously
    if (document.getElementById("ddlLanguages").options.selectedIndex == 11 /*Azure*/) return;

    if (document.getElementsByName('ImageType')[0].checked) {
        var uploadIndexes = [];
        for (var i = DWObject.HowManyImagesInBuffer - 1; i > -1 ; i--) {
            uploadIndexes.push(i);
        }
        var uploadJPGsOneByOne = function (errorCode, errorString, sHttpResponse) {
            if (upload_returnSth)
                _printUploadedFiles(sHttpResponse);
            if (uploadIndexes.length > 0) {
                var _index = uploadIndexes.pop();
                if (upload_returnSth)
                    DWObject.HTTPUploadThroughPost(strHTTPServer, _index, strActionPage, uploadfilename + "-" + _index.toString() + ".jpg", OnHttpUploadSuccess, uploadJPGsOneByOne);
                else
                    DWObject.HTTPUploadThroughPost(strHTTPServer, _index, strActionPage, uploadfilename + "-" + _index.toString() + ".jpg", uploadJPGsOneByOne, OnHttpServerReturnedSomething);
            }
        }
        var _index = uploadIndexes.pop();
        if (upload_returnSth)
            DWObject.HTTPUploadThroughPost(strHTTPServer, _index, strActionPage, uploadfilename + "-" + _index.toString() + ".jpg", OnHttpUploadSuccess, uploadJPGsOneByOne);
        else
            DWObject.HTTPUploadThroughPost(strHTTPServer, _index, strActionPage, uploadfilename + "-" + _index.toString() + ".jpg", uploadJPGsOneByOne, OnHttpServerReturnedSomething);
    }
    else if (document.getElementsByName('ImageType')[1].checked) {
        DWObject.HTTPUploadAllThroughPostAsMultiPageTIFF(strHTTPServer, strActionPage, uploadfilename + ".tif", OnHttpUploadSuccess, OnHttpServerReturnedSomething);
    }
    else if (document.getElementsByName('ImageType')[2].checked) {
        DWObject.HTTPUploadAllThroughPostAsPDF(strHTTPServer, strActionPage, uploadfilename + ".pdf", OnHttpUploadSuccess, OnHttpServerReturnedSomething);
    }
}

function UploadImage() {
    if (DWObject) {
        var nCount = 0, nCountUpLoaded = 0, aryFilePaths = [];
        if (document.getElementById('uploadDirectly').checked) {
            DWObject.IfShowCancelDialogWhenImageTransfer = false;
            function ds_load_file_to_upload_directly(bSave, filesCount, index, path, filename) {
                nCount = filesCount;
                var filePath = path + "\\" + filename;
                aryFilePaths.push(filePath);
                if (aryFilePaths.length == nCount) {
                    upload_preparation();
                    var i = 0;
                    function uploadFileOneByOne() {
                        DWObject.HTTPUploadThroughPostDirectly(strHTTPServer, filePath, strActionPage, filename,
                            function () {
                                console.log('Upload Image:' + aryFilePaths[i] + ' -- successful');
                                i++;
                                if (i != nCount)
                                    uploadFileOneByOne();
                                else
                                    DWObject.UnregisterEvent('OnGetFilePath', ds_load_file_to_upload_directly);
                            },
                            OnHttpServerReturnedSomething
                        );
                    }
                    uploadFileOneByOne();
                }
            }
            DWObject.RegisterEvent('OnGetFilePath', ds_load_file_to_upload_directly);
            DWObject.ShowFileDialog(false, "Any File | *.*", 0, "", "", true, true, 0);
        }
        else {
            UploadImage_inner();
        }
    }
}


/*******************/
/* Upload to Azure */

var Base64Binary = {
    _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
    decode: function (input, arrayBuffer) {
        //get last chars to see if are valid
        var lkey1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(input.length - 1));
        var lkey2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(input.length - 2));
        var bytes = (input.length / 4) * 3;
        if (lkey1 == 64) bytes--; //padding chars, so skip
        if (lkey2 == 64) bytes--; //padding chars, so skip      
        var uarray;
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;
        if (arrayBuffer)
            uarray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        else
            uarray = new Uint8Array(bytes);
        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
        for (i = 0; i < bytes; i += 3) {
            //get the 3 octects in 4 ascii chars
            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(j++));
            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;
            uarray[i] = chr1;
            if (enc3 != 64) uarray[i + 1] = chr2;
            if (enc4 != 64) uarray[i + 2] = chr3;
        }
        return uarray;
    }
}

function uploadImageInner_azure(blobSasUrl, fileDataAsArrayBuffer) {
    var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try {
        ajaxRequest.open('PUT', blobSasUrl, true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
        ajaxRequest.send(fileDataAsArrayBuffer);
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
                console.log('Upload image to azure server successfully.');
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("can't upload the image to server.\n" + e.toString());
    }
}

function preparetoUploadtoAzure(__name) {
    var uploadfilename = '';
    //For JPEG, upload the current image
    if (document.getElementsByName('ImageType')[0].checked) {
        DWObject.SelectedImagesCount = 1;
        DWObject.SetSelectedImageIndex(0, DWObject.CurrentImageIndexInBuffer);
        DWObject.GetSelectedImagesSize(EnumDWT_ImageType.IT_JPG);
        uploadfilename = __name + '.jpg';
    }
    else { //For TIFF, PDF, upload all images
        var count = DWObject.HowManyImagesInBuffer;
        DWObject.SelectedImagesCount = count;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            DWObject.SetSelectedImageIndex(i, i);
        }
        if (document.getElementsByName('ImageType')[1].checked) {
            DWObject.GetSelectedImagesSize(EnumDWT_ImageType.IT_TIF);
            uploadfilename = __name + '.tif';
        }
        else {
            DWObject.GetSelectedImagesSize(EnumDWT_ImageType.IT_PDF);
            uploadfilename = __name + '.pdf';
        }
    }

    var strImg, aryImg, _uint8_STR, _bin_ARR, _blobImg;
    strImg = DWObject.SaveSelectedImagesToBase64Binary();
    // convert base64 to Uint8Array
    var bytes = (strImg.length / 4) * 3;
    var _temp = new ArrayBuffer(bytes);
    _uint8_STR = Base64Binary.decode(strImg, _temp);

    // convert Uint8Array to blob
    _blobImg = new Blob([_uint8_STR]);
    // upload to Azure server
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            uploadImageInner_azure(xhr.responseText, _blobImg);
        }
    }
    var actionPageFullPath = CurrentPath + 'action/' + 'azure.aspx?imageName=' + uploadfilename;
    xhr.open('GET', actionPageFullPath, true);
    xhr.send();
}
/*******************/
```

Comment: This feels a bit broad. Have you integrated any part of this library at all? Judging by your links, it has a JavaScript component, and a server-side requirement ([such as this one](https://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/document-imaging/how-to-scan-documents-in-php/)). I would guess that if you want to add additional fields, insert them in the client-side form, and then you can read them in your server-side POST operation when retrieving the uploaded files.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "wanting this permanent"?

Comment: @halfer - if you look at the demo, you can click a little plus sign and add one or multiple rows of field names and values, which are passed through to the post using the script file they have provided for that specific example. But as you can see, the output from above is what is POSTed to the server. It's not like "this_is_field":"wow" that I have seen before, this is rather new to me. And as for your other comment, the data is passed through not really as a form, but as a script which then somehow formats it

Comment: I've added the script that is currently in use -- and sorry about the editing.

Comment: OK, so if you have the JavaScript that powers the demo, trace where the "+" button is handled, and examine the code that produces key-value pair fields. Implement your fields using that code at DOM load time, rather than when the "+" button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for using Dynamic Web TWAIN. Yes, SetHTTPFormField is the right method to post additional fields to the server side. 
Feel free to contact support(at)dynamsoft.com and our team will happy to help you get it working.